# Does mod_status keep X-FORWARDED-FOR header?

Tags: apache-http-server, amazon-web-services

I have a server behind loadbalencer (Amazon ELB), which hides people's IP address when connections come to web servers.

However it sends the IP address of the visitor in X-FORWARDED-FOR header.

I was wondering if I would be able to use some kind of tool along with Apache's mod_status to retrieve a list of currently active connections and their originating IP addresses.

Comment: I'd love to figure out how to get mod_status to display X-FORWARDED-FOR header IPs instead of 127.0.0.1 for such situations. You can easily do it in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html, why not in mod_status?

Answer (score 0):

So this comes late but sharing here for reference.

Apparently mod_status picks up the IP from apache logs. So you need to have the mod_remoteip enabled and setup right.

```
<IfModule remoteip_module>
        RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
        RemoteIPProxiesHeader X-Forwarded-By
</IfModule>
```

And finally start using this info in the logs:

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/other_vhosts_access.log "%v:%p %a %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
```

The %a variable is the Client IP address of the request and %h is the remote hostname. Will log the IP address if HostnameLookups is set to Off, which is the default.